# Nagios - unable to read output

Tags: linux, bash, nagios, nrpe

I make custom bash script to monitor ssh failed logins - which locally runs ok -  on nagios server and remote hosts.

```
root@xxx:/usr/local/nagios/libexec# ./check_bruteforce_ssh.sh -c 20 -w 50
OK - no constant bruteforce attack
```

But on nagios page - shows **Unable to read output**

I make so changes in configs to verify form https://support.nagios.com/kb/article/nrpe-nrpe-unable-to-read-output-620.html what's going wrong and I cannot find out where is the problem.

Script runs via nrpe which run on all machine

```
root@test:/usr/local/nagios/libexec# ./check_nrpe -H test1
NRPE v3.2.1
```

When I tested script via nrpe I've got problem with

```
NRPE: Command 'check_bruteforce_ssh' not defined
```

which is defined in nrpe.cfg

```
command[check_bruteforce_attack]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_bruteforce_attack.sh -w 20 -c 50
```

All permissions for user nagios is added - in sudoers etc.

Where can I find the solution or somedoby got similar problem?

Comment: So the remote script is `check_bruteforce_ssh.sh` but you have configured `check_bruteforce_attack.sh`

Comment: no I see the problem - after fix it - everything works fine

Comment: Sometimes the problem is right in front of your nose, but you just can't see it. Happens to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your definition.
Replace `check_bruteforce_attack` in `nrpe.cfg` with `check_bruteforce_ssh` and it will work ;-)